# How can users be hinted to mention software/language version when asking?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, language-versions

Those who are familiar with [MATLAB's changes over time](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/release-notes.html) know that in the last few versions there is a growing transition to OOP to perform all sorts of computations and return their results. One of the most noticeable changes is the new "handle graphics" system ([matlab-hg2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/matlab-hg2)).

I would go so far as claiming that most casual MATLAB users aren't familiar with the [`ver`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ver.html) command (which outputs the version of all installed products) nor with the fact that there's a line at the end of the help pages that says when these functions were added, such as:

> **Introduced before R2006a**

As the version of MATLAB is almost never mentioned by askers, I find myself quite often asking via a comment *which release of MATLAB they are using*, because like other languages, there are functionality changes\additions etc, which affect the runnablility of answers (i.e. I don't want to suggest a solution based on a function(ality) added in the latest MATLAB when the other party has a 3-yo version).

I think that in some languages it is more important to mention the version used, and MATLAB is one of these languages (most of the time).

My question is how can askers be notified that they should mention the software version used?

---

In the case of questions about figures\plots - it makes sense to auto-suggest [matlab-hg2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/matlab-hg2), but even then, casual users will most likely not be aware of the reason behind their graphics becoming prettier all of a sudden when they installed a new version, and thus will not think they should select it (even though this is vital information).

Comment: If you look at [tag:python], the excerpt includes *"Two similar but incompatible versions of Python are in widespread use (2 and 3). Please consider mentioning the version and implementation that you are using when asking a question about Python."* Perhaps something similar could be adopted for other tags? Caveat: on the whole the people who don't bother tagging versions aren't reading the tag excerpts, either.

Comment: Mentioning a version is common sense and is pretty much mandatory for any aspect of software engineering. Take web frameworks as an example: how you would solve a particular problem or requirement is usually different in newer iterations simply because there are better tools available to do the job. So not mentioning the version makes it very vague exactly what you can answer. I'm not really a fan of SO needing to tell people what common sense is outside of the site help.

Comment: jonrsharpe - I completely agree with the last statement. @Gimby - Wouldn't you say that disciplining people into properly asking questions (i.e. mentioning all relevant information) would benefit everybody? Maybe it should be mandatory to include a version where applicable....

Comment: 95% of the questions I see in [tag:JavaScript] don't mention version, @Gimby.

Comment: @Dev-iL It is also mandatory to follow the rules for asking and answering questions. Does saying that make it so? Heck no.

Comment: @Gimby - I meant in the sense that it's some field you should fill out like "Title" and can't proceed otherwise. Not mandatory as in "the way you should do things"... It makes sense if SO is mainly about programming...

Comment: @Cerbrus I think I prefer the javascript questions which don't mention version and/or framework, because then you get answers by a variety of people which cover many versions and frameworks. Especially on older questions. You'll have one answer describing how to do it with jQuery, another with plain ES5, another with plain ES6, another using lodash. And then as the reader you get to learn about all these different features and approaches, and pick the one that best fits what you want.